# Python/ Как найти расстояние наиболее удаленных концов ближайших отрезков

Tags: python, алгоритм

Даны несколько отрезков на плоскости. Как можно сначала найти 2 близлежащих отрезка, а затем расстояние наиболее удаленных концов этих отрезков?

Например, даны три отрезка (формата x1, y1, x2, y2):

```
1 1 1 2
2 3 1 3
0 5 2 6
```

Ближайшие отрезки - 1 и 2

Наиболее дальние концы этих отрезков - (1, 1) и (2, 3)

Ответ - расстояние между ними:

```
3.605551275463989
```

Пробовал решать обычным способом:

1)Перебор всех сумм всех отрезков,

2)определение минимума,

3)определение наиболее удаленных концов отрезков друг от друга,

4)расчет длины.

Но данный "алгоритм" очень долгий.

Comment: А что вы уже попробовали?

Comment: Что значит "два близлежащих отрезка"? Какой критерий "близлежащести"?

Comment: @Harry Отрезки, расстояние между отрезками должно быть наименьшим (https://grafika.me/node/947)

Comment: @MBo, в том то и проблема, найти оптимального алгоритма не смог, добавил этот момент в задачу

Comment: Не понял, что значит в вашем алгоритме "перебор сумм всех отрезков". За O(N^2) можно просто перебрать все пары отрезков, найдя пару с минимальным расстоянием, а потом уже максимальное расстояние между концами. Или это слишком медленно? Сколько всего отрезков намечается? "Несколько" — это 10? 100? 100000?

Comment: @ Harry, до 200

Comment: 200 отрезков - 20000 пар - совсем немного, если вам не приходится пересчитывать данные каждую микросекунду.